# rvalue and lvalue reference with lambda expressions - gcc vs. msvc

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

In C++, it is illegal to implicitly convert an rvalue to an lvalue reference.
Consider the following code where an lvalue reference is bound to an rvalue (the lambda):

```
int main()
{
    auto& f = []() -> void {};
    return 0;
}
```

gcc (4.8.1) does not accept such code (makes perfect sense).
However, Microsoft compiler does accept it meaning that either it is accepting nonstandard code or C++ allows the particular case where an lvalue reference is bound to an rvalue lambda expression.

The question: which assumption is correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The core of your question is: can *rvalues* be bound to **non-const** *lvalue* references?

The Standard says **no**. *rvalues* can only be bound to **const** *lvalue* references.

I believe the relevant Standard paragraph is **8.5.3/5**:

> A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2 T2” as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, the reference shall be an lvalue reference to a non-volatile **const** type (i.e., cv1 shall be const), or the reference
>     shall be an rvalue reference.

However Microsoft has a long-standing "feature" that allows this **non-standard** behaviour, which explains what you're witnessing.

Comment: Yes, it is a feature. It's useful sometimes. Do we have a question/answer around somewhere that explains this?

Comment: @MartinBa: In reply to both your comments, anything outside the standard is, IMHO, not a feature but a bug. C++ isn't perfect but vendor-specific "improvements" are a PITA when it comes to interoperability and they should be killed with fire. YMMV (but when you start working on cross-platform projects this becomes very important).

Comment: @syam: Many vendor-specific extensions are essential. Nobody would get anywhere without OS-specific APIs.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you *really* trying to compare APIs with core language features? The standard already gives enough (and IMO way too much) leeway to implementations, but OS APIs have *nothing* to do with the core language features.

Comment: If you turn on warning level 4 in MSVC, you get warnings about use of nonstandard extensions.  Given this, I don't see the harm of having some convenient language extensions available to those who are writing to a single platform.

Comment: @MikeWoolf: Well I don't know much about MSVC since I haven't used it for ages but I know about GCC: any non-standard extensions require you to explicitly **opt-in** or face a warning. IMO this is much more sane than MSVC requiring you to **opt-out**. Again, YMMV.

Comment: @syam, my point is that it is easy to use MSVC for cross platform work.  I truly don't see any particular advantage one way or the other with opt-out versus opt-in.  If you're writing production code, you're responsible for learning such basics about the tools you use.  If you're a hobbyist, you're probably not writing cross platform code.

Comment: @MikeWoolf: True enough. :) Still, I believe hobbyists should be taught (by the tools they use, not just by the internet community) how to become professionals. How can you learn to write proper production-ready code if you're taught non-standard crap? ;)

Comment: @syam, you're right - and the OP's question is a perfect case in point.

Answer (score 3):

> However, Microsoft compiler does accept it meaning that either it is accepting nonstandard code or C++ allows the particular case where an lvalue reference is bound to an rvalue lambda expression.

MSVC is known for having this (not so great) compiler extension. It simply allows binding rvalues to lvalue references to non-`const`:

```
A& x = A(); // Illegal in C++, allowed by MSVC
```

Comment: The feature makes some sense for function parameters: `void f(A& a) { ... }` can be called with `... f(A()); ...` which *has* its use cases.

Comment: @MartinBa: I am really not keen on this extension. First of all because this is a major behavior change with respect to the standard, and secondly because it bites you more often than it helps you.

Comment: @Martin Ba: This makes multiplatform development more complicated if you first develop on MS and then test on other platforms...from time to time you use an rvalue for a non-const lvalue reference and MSVC wont tell you. So it shows up a bit later on GCC...Always annoying. At least a compiler switch to turn it off in MSVC would be a nice thing!!

Answer (score 3):

To [quote](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) Herb Sutter (chair of the ISO C++ standards committee):

> A conforming C++ compiler can always allow otherwise-illegal C++ code to compile and give it some meaning — hey, it could choose to allow inline COBOL if some kooky compiler writer was willing to implement that extension, maybe after a few too many Tequilas. For some kinds of extensions the C++ standard requires that the compiler at least emit some diagnostic to say that the code isn’t valid ISO C++, as this compiler does.

He explains further how the following example is illegal:

```
// Example 2

string f() { return "abc"; }

void g() {
string& s = f();       // illegal?
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

Please visit this [link](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/) by Sutter for an explanation, to avoid duplicating the article on SO.